# Metadata tags in Nextjs not recognized in google search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, metadata

I'm working on a project built with Next.js and JavaScript. I tried to follow the Next.js documentation provided here ([Optimizing: Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata)), which states that by declaring constants with metadata tags, it should automatically generate the Head section of the page containing the metadata declared in the constant. When inspecting the page locally, it works exactly as described. However, the issue is that Google doesn't seem to correctly read this type of tag, so the title and description on my site were missing, and Google was reading random h2 tags.

Here's an example of the page where I tried to insert the metadata:

```
// Metadata

export const metadata = {
  title: "MySite",
  description:
    "My site talks about this...",
};

//Layout//

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Subsequently, I tried manually writing the Head tag on my page, adding title and description tags and including the declared variable inside them. After checking on Google, I discovered that this latter method works because Google correctly reads the title and description of the site. Here's an example of how I modified the code:

```
// Metadata

export const metadata = {
  title: "MySite",
  description:
    "My site talks about this...",
};

//Layout//

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
        <Head>
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <description>{metadata.description}</description>
        </Head>
      <body>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I wanted to ask if anyone else had encountered the same issue and had resolved it in a similar manner. The Next.js documentation doesn't mention this problem because it should automate the creation of the Head and meta tags, but it seems that Google doesn't accept it.

Comment: When handling SEO in NextJS I usually just use next-seo package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo

But from what I can see, you aren't using the correct tag for SEO. The description meta tag should look like this: 
```<meta name="description" content="My site talks about this...">```
And the title should look like this:
```<meta name="og:title" property="og:title" content="MySite">```

Comment: As for the static exports of the metadata, can you confirm if you're using the app router? Because I think this will only work within the app router.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I can confirm I'm using the app router, been using it the whole project. About the description meta tags: I have tried to use the meta tags written that way (like google suggests) and neither the titles nor the description could work.
` <meta name="description" content="My site talks about this...">` the traditional code, like this, didn't work for google.
the only way I could make it work was the second solution I have posted and couldn't explain why.

Comment: @Giammy there is no <description> tag - are you using <meta name="description" content="" /> ? I approached same issue